# What is self-intersecting for a polytope?

Tags: geometry

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_polyhedron#Star_polytopes):

> Self-intersecting polytopes in any dimension are called star polytopes.

How is a polytope being self-intersecting defined? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on your definition of a polytope. If it's some collection of faces (edges, vertices, ...) then it will be self-intersecting if there is some pair of faces that intersect each other non-trivially (meaning they just don't share a common subface of the polytope).